# Active Record includes with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

I have the following model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

class Student < User
  has_one  :student_detail

class StudentDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school

class Staff < User
  has_one :staff_detail

class StaffDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
```

The StudentDetail and StaffDetails have additional information, I am trying to avoid having it all in one STI user table due to having to work with something similar to **concrete class per table pattern**

I can do this easily enough

```
Event.includes(:attendances => :user).where(...)
```

but I want to be able to includes depending on user type
e.g.

```
Event.includes(attendances: {:user => :student_details })
```

This will fail as some of the users are Staff objects.

I realise rails won't support this out of the box, but anyone have any tricks to get this to work

best solution right now would be split user on attendance to student and staff 
i.e.

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, -> {includes(:staff_detail) }
  belongs_to :staff, -> {includes(:student_detail) }
  #belong_to :user
```

which isn't ideal.
Anyone have any tips? way to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to just move the `has_one` associations down on to user. Since only `Staff` records will have `staff_details`, the preloading will just work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :staff_detail
  has_one :student_detail
end

class Staff < User; end
class Student < User; end
```

That's not ideal though. To customise preloading further, you can use the `Preloader` class in Rails. First, load all the records *without* any includes, then iterate over them and preload the associations you need:

```
events = Event.includes(:attendances => :user)
users = events.users.flatten
users.group_by(&:class).each do |klass, records|
  associations = {
    Staff:   [:staff_detail],
    Student: [:student_detail]
  }.fetch(klass, [])

  ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records, associations).run
end
```

Note that this API [changed in Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3022). In versions 3 and earlier, you just used the [`preload_associations`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AssociationPreload/ClassMethods/preload_associations) method.

A while back I wrote a [blog post about this same problem](http://rhnh.net/2010/08/15/class-table-inheritance-and-eager-loading) which includes a couple of other neat tricks (such as spec'ing that you get correct behaviour).

Comment: The syntax changed again, for Rails 4.1 I beleive. The new syntax is `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(records, associations)`. See [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6e5a2cb9519aab568ea0cfea2f42364de8ccf655) for details.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting the `includes` on the STI models as a `default_scope`?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

class Student < User
  has_one  :student_detail
  default_scope includes(:student_detail)

class StudentDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school

class Staff < User
  has_one :staff_detail
  default_scope includes(:staff_detail)

class StaffDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Then I think this:

```
Event.includes(:attendances => :user).where(...)
```

Should eager load for both Students and Staff.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use named scopes to make your life a little easier.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  scope :for_students, -> { includes(:attendances => { :users => :student_detail }).where('users.type = ?', 'Student') }
  scope :for_staff, -> { includes(:attendances => { :users => :staff_detail }).where('users.type = ?', 'Staff') }
end
```

Then you can just do `Event.for_students`